# Is there an easy way to resize/expand an image with only zeros in Python or PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I would like to resize larger. However, the Image.resize from PIL interpolates the image (I think). I just want this image expanded with zeros filled in. For example, if I had a small image like this:

```
 1,2,3,4,5 
 1,2,3,4,5
```

and if I wanted to expand its horizontal axis to double its size, I want:

```
 1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,0
 1,0,2,0,3,0,4,5,0
```

Or something else approximate like that.

Also, is there a real name to this in image processing?

Comment: can you post an input and desired output image as well. It would help a lot in sorting the problem

Comment: you want to expand the image by adding black pixels?

Comment: @alexis correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` as:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png', 0) #a dummy file

img2 = np.zeros([img.shape[0], 2*img.shape[1]])
img2[0::1, 0::2] = img[0::1, 0::1]
```